# REDIRECT LOOP message on the home page of the site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to make 2 redirects using .htaccess.

1. Move all pages of the site from .html to .php
2. Remove index.php from the home page's URL.

Here's what I have by now:

```
### 1_move from html to php
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ http://example.com$1.php

### 2_remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
```

Each of the redirects works fine by itself but they don't want to work together.
Actually all pages except index.php work okay. And instead of the home page I get a message:

**This webpage has a redirect loop.**

If I comment any of the redirects, the home page comes back.

How can I befriend them? What am I doing wrong? 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure how your problem is caused, but you could take a look at `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` to debug your problem.

Comment: I wouldn't use both mod_alias and mod_rewrite together but try clearing your cache since you're doing 301s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
### Switch from .html to .php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html /$1.php [R=301,L]

### removes index.php
RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [QSA,R]
```

This way they work together.